# magento 2 installation on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php-7, apache2

I have a small problem.
I have installed the new magento 2 on a ubuntu 16-04 server
with php 7.0.

I installed everything OK, now errors..
The i whant to install extension..
and i got this:

So i test to make a new crob.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

And i still cant install extension.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: What happens if you copy and paste this in your command line?  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run

Comment: I get Ran jobs by schedule

Comment: Please only use the first line in your cron schedule. Furthermore, which errors are you getting in the PHP extensions check?

Comment: hello, i did´t see any errors, only missing php extension